# java Split one list into multiple lists by exclusion of elements

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

There is a List in which the elements are mutually exclusive according to certain conditions

1. Now I need to split into multiple Lists according to this mutual exclusion condition
2. Mutually exclusive elements cannot appear in a child List after partitioning
3. The number of child Lists after segmentation should be minimized

-------------For example----------------------

1. Original list [A, B, C]
2. A and C are mutually exclusive, A and B are not mutually exclusive, and B and C are not mutually exclusive
3. It can be divided into [A], [B, C] or [C], [A, B]
4. Do not split into [A], [B], [C], because the total number of sub lists after splitting is not the minimum

Who can help me?

Comment: Could you provide some examples please?

Comment: The language in your description seems to be all over the place. Make it consistent. When you say split into multiple lists, do you mean partition the original list according to the mutual exclusive condition? Also, point number 2 talks about child lists. What is a child list? Do you mean the subsets of the partition. So are you saying that elements in one subset of the partition cannot be in another subset of the same partition (mutually exclusive)? If so, you are essentially describing the definition of a partition

Comment: Does the condition for mutual exclusivity always result in a boolean? If so, the condition will yield two subsets. Or can this condition result in more than two values?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: For example,

1. Original list [A, B, C]

2. A and C are mutually exclusive, a and B are not mutually exclusive, and B and C are not mutually exclusive

3. It can be divided into [A], [B, C] or [C], [A, B]

4. Do not split into [A], [B], [C], because the total number of sub lists after splitting is not the minimum

Comment: It's a little bit like the groupby method in the lamda expression in Java 8, but groupby can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to partition a set elements based on an arbitrary comparison between any two elements in the set. I don't think java comes with that functionality out of the box. One way you can do that is the following:

```java
public class Partition<T> {

    public List<Set<T>> partition(List<T> list, BiPredicate<T, T> partitionCondtion) {
        List<Set<T>> partition = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            // get first element from the remaining elements on the original list
            T firstElement = list.remove(0);

            // add first element into a subset
            // all elements on this subset must not be mutually exclusive with firstElement
            Set<T> subset = new HashSet<>();
            subset.add(firstElement);

            // get all remaining elements which can reside in the same subset of
            // firstElement
            List<T> notMutuallyExclusive = list.stream().filter(e -> !partitionCondtion.test(firstElement, e))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            // add them to the subset of firstElement
            subset.addAll(notMutuallyExclusive);

            // add subset to partition (list of subsets)
            partition.add(subset);

            // remove elements added from original list
            list.removeAll(notMutuallyExclusive);
        }

        return partition;
    }

}
```

You can test your scenario like this:

```java
public class PartitionSmallTest {

    private BiPredicate<String, String> areMutuallyExclusive() {
        return (left, right) -> ("A".equals(left) && "C".equals(right)) || ("C".equals(left) && "A".equals(right));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

        List<Set<String>> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.add(Set.of("A", "B"));
        expected.add(Set.of("C"));

        List<Set<String>> actual = new Partition<String>().partition(list, areMutuallyExclusive());

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```